# paper-header-panel - assigning handler to event content-scroll manually

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

Using polymer 1.1, I don't want to make a custom element or template for `paper-header-panel`. How can I assign a handler on the scroll event?

I tried:

```
bob = Polymer.dom(document).querySelector('paper-header-panel');
bob.scrollHandler = function() {
  console.log('ssssssss');
}
```

To no success.

https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-header-panel/blob/master/paper-header-panel.html#L186

From documentation

> ```
> Polymer({
>   is: 'paper-header-panel',
>   /**
>    * Fired when the content has been scrolled.  `event.detail.target` returns
>    * the scrollable element which you can use to access scroll info such as
>    * `scrollTop`.
>    *
>    *     <paper-header-panel on-content-scroll="{{scrollHandler}}">
>    *       ...
>    *     </paper-header-panel>
>    *
>    *
>    *     scrollHandler: function(event) {
>    *       var scroller = event.detail.target;
>    *       console.log(scroller.scrollTop);
>    *     }
>    *
>    * @event content-scroll
>    */
> ```

and

> ```
>   ready: function() {
>     this.scrollHandler = this._scroll.bind(this);
>     this._addListener();
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to subscribe the event in js like this -

```
ready: function () {
    this.$.panel.addEventListener("content-scroll", function () {
        console.log('ssssssss');
    });
}
```

But I failed to see why you can't do it like shown in the document.

---

```
bob = Polymer.dom(document).querySelector('paper-header-panel');
bob.addEventListener("content-scroll", function () {
    console.log('ssssssss');
}
```

Comment: This won't work for me. I don't want to make `paper-header-panel` a custom element or template it. If so, the whole web app would be in a template or custom element. So the way I posted above is the only way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean? The `paper-header-panel` itself is a custom element already made for you...

Comment: Ok, but for the sake of the original question I would still like to know how.